# Why does a lookup in Map in this particular code take such a surprisingly long time?

Tags: scala, hashmap, scala-collections

I have the following data structures:

```
val set: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = ...
val test1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]] = ...
val test2: Array[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]] = ...
```

`set` contains about 60,000 entires. `test1` has two entries ("one" and "two") and each is a Set of Strings similar to `set`. `test2` is similar to `test1` but the keys are 0 and 1 instead.

Running `test1.get("one").get.contains("somestring")` takes a long time (about 1 second) but running `test2(0).contains("somestring")` is very fast.

I don't quite understand why there is such a big difference. Any ideas?

Comment: If you assume that the map has "one" as an key entry, then you should call `test1("one").contains("somestring")`

Comment: @Kigyo Thanks for the note, it definitely looks better. However, the `apply` method has the same performance as the `get` method in my test.

Comment: Like others said: We need more information regarding your code.

Comment: How can we answer this question if you don't paste the actual implementation used for test1? Can't guess much from an interface...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `mapValues` on an existing Map to generate the new Map. I thought `mapValues` works similarly to `map` but in reality `mapValues` only creates a View on the existing Map instead of a new Map.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
test2(0)
```

Runs really fast because it's an array, it knows exactly where `0` is, the map has to find the "one" key first and then get's it's pair.

Comment: It's obvious that an Array is faster than a Map, the question is why the Map is so _tremendously_ slow, even though it only has two entries. It takes much more time than the contains lookup in the Set with 60,000 entries.

Comment: And how are you benchmarking this? I can't measure the time to run `map("one")` using `System.currentTimeInMillis()`. It's always zero.

Comment: @flavian he said he's seeing a **one second** difference. And with only two keys the worst case scenario is two comparisons inside a hash bucket, the amount of operations is negligible.

Comment: Sorry guys, I did not provide the full problem details! After more testing I've found that the problem was that I created the Map using the `mapValues` method, and I did not know that it only created a View on the old Map instead of a new Map. Sorry for wasting your time. :(

Answer (score 1):

Running this code to generate some collections like you mentioned:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{HashSet, HashMap}
import scala.util.Random

def genSet(count: Int = 100 * 1000, stringSize: Int = 10): Set[String] = {
  val set = new HashSet[String]
  set.sizeHint(count)

  for(i <- 1 to count) {
    set.add(i.toString)
  }

  set.toSet
} 

def genSetMap(count: Int = 2, keySize: Int = 10)
             (f: => Set[String]): Map[String, Set[String]] = {
  val map = new HashMap[String, Set[String]]
  map.sizeHint(count)

  for(i <- 1 to count) {
    map.put(i.toString, genSet())
  }

  map.toMap
}
```

The following test, using 100.000 elements per set, still runs instantly:

```
val map = genSetMap(2, 10){ genSet(100*1000) }
map("2").contains("99999") // res2: Boolean = true
```

So I suspect there is some peculiarity in your actual code that is causing it not to generate a set, but some other intermediate collection that doesn't have fast searching. Can you provide a more concrete example of the actual code you are seeing the behavior with?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. You are right, the problem was in the code that was not part of the question. The Map I was using was created using the `mapValues` method which only creates a View on the old Map instead of a new Map.